# Calculate the dimensions of a Google Static Map in Degrees

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate the width and height(in degrees) of a Satellite image returned by Google Static Maps.

**My Problem:** I dont think I am correctly calculating the height(in degrees) of the satellite image.

Do you know how to calculate the height of this satellite image?

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-32,151&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=true

The following code can correctly calculate the width of the satellite image in Degrees but not the height:

```
var meshWidthDeg  = (imgWidth/256f)*(360f / Math.Pow(2f,zoom));
var meshHeightDeg = (imgHeight/256f)*(360f / Math.Pow(2f,zoom));
var elevArea       = new Array(lat - (meshWidthDeg/2), lon - (meshHeightDeg/2), 
                                   meshWidthDeg, meshHeightDeg);
```

Comment: The height is far more difficult because the Mercator projection varies with latitude. The vertical scale is different at the top of the map from the bottom (horizontal scale is constant, as you found).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Do you know of a formula or method I could use to calculate it?